# Way for resolving "Temporary file write failure" in case of select statement

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, microservices

We are facing a strange issue. In one of our service ( There are around 12 to 13 services in application) while executing SQL query ( select statement ) which returns around 30 40 rows and takes less than a second to execute.

We are intermittently getting "Temporary file write failure" exception

Below is the piece of code

```
 Query qry = null;

  //selectquery is of type String whose value is read from properties file using @Value("${})
  qry = entityManager.createNativeQuery(selectquery);
              //set few parameters here   
             
            
 List result = qry.getResultList();
```

We are getting below exception

```
<Log_Created_Date: 2020/08/11 17:59:21> <Log_Level: ERROR> <application_name: abc> <Class_Name: com.pqr> <Method_Name: someMethod> <Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Temporary file write failure.
```

Complete error log is as below

```
<Log_Created_Date: 2020/08/11 17:59:21> <Log_Level: ERROR> <application_name: abc> <Class_Name: com.pqr> <Method_Name: someMethod> <Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Temporary file write failure.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:82)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:82)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
        ... 158 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:69)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2167)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1930)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1892)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501)
        at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2223)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1053)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:168)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1506)
        ... 144 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:149)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1515)
        at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146)
        at com.pqr.someMethod(pqr.java:259)
```

Out of all services this exception is coming only in one of the service.We are connecting to same Database from all the services. **The difference between other services and this one is that it is being used much more frequently.**

We are not altering anything neither we are trying to create anything. It is simple select statement.

We checked temp space (/tmp directory on DB server ) and ample amount of it is free every time this exception occurs.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: I still think it is a disk space issue. Can you double check from your mysql config my.cnf which directory is used as "tempdir"?

Comment: @cool /Mysql/tmp is being user as tempdir

Answer (score 0):

This happened to be database/server related issue.

Increasing value of ulimit parameter on server where DB is deployed/running resolved this issue.

**MySQL uses temporary tables for resolving complicated queries.**